# Matlab - stacking Image (2d slices)

Tags: image, matlab

I have a set of projected 2D images (format double,) for making a tomograph. I have used iradon and created a tomograph along(XZ). Now I need to stack some of those layers ( say every 10th layer) into a new 3D space for visualization. kindly suggest a way for doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `meshgrid` and `surf` e.g.:

```
A = rand(10); %Your images
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,2));
Z1 = ones(size(A))*10;
surf(X,Y,Z1,A)
Z2 = ones(size(A))*1;
hold on
surf(X,Y,Z2,rand(10))
```

[image]

[Also this might interest you](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1713-three-dimensional-reconstruction-from-planar-slices)